# every click registers as Right Click

Tags: trackpad

I'm on 11.1 and sometimes after opening my laptop every click registes as "Right Click". This both with internal and external trackpad. It's as if "CTRL" is permanently pressed whenever I click (it is remapped to CAPS on my laptop). I've had similar problem with older versions of mac as well (perhaps related to CAPS/CTRL switch?)

The only solution I found that works is to restart my laptop. Any idea if there's a quicker workaround?

Comment: Try connecting an external keyboard. If the symptom does not appear, then there's something awry with the built-in keyboard.

Comment: I'd try inspecting and cleaning the keyboard. You're right. It does sound like something's up with the CTRL key. Another thing to try -- try unmapping the CTRL as CAPS and see if that changes anything.